# How to force @RestController to encode body to specific encoding?

Tags: java, spring, encoding, spring-restcontroller

I have a controller with `produces` set to

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
```

over RestController

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/xml;charset=windows-1251")
```

With POSTman I get response like `<tag field="РђР±РѕРЅРµРЅС‚ РЅР°Р№РґРµРЅ"/>` which looks like UTF-8 bytes being decoded to windows-1251 and then flushed to the HTTP response.

But in fact, I need just my UTF-8 String with the same characters, but just in windows-1251 encoding. What I should change in the body to make it flushed with the encoding I expect, not only changing the headers of the HTTP response?

Comment: You say 'XML string'. Generally putting XML into strings isn't a good idea as it results in encoding problems sooner or later. Use byte arrays instead. But I think your problem here is that your XML document is already serialized using UTF-8. The framework will return it as it is. Either let the framework do the encooding using JAXB or serialize it for yourself using the desired encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fount, that XML was forcibly recoded to windows-1251 on the accepting side:

```
@Override
public T handleResponse(HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    if (statusLine.getStatusCode() != 200) {
        LOGGER.error("Status code: " + statusLine.getStatusCode());
        throw new HttpResponseException(statusLine.getStatusCode(), statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
    }

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity == null) {
        throw new ClientProtocolException("Response contains no content");
    }

    // only for logging
    String xml = IOUtils.toString(entity.getContent(), "windows-1251");
    entity.getContent().close();
    if (responseClass == GetUIProvidersResponse.class) {
        LOGGER.info("Logging for getUIProviders is disabled");
    } else {
        LOGGER.info(xml);
    }

    return xmlMapper.readValue(xml, responseClass);
}
```

for making response to be encoded in true windows-1251 I had to update `DispatcherServlet` extension:

```
public class LoggableDispatcherServlet extends DispatcherServlet {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggableDispatcherServlet.class);

    public LoggableDispatcherServlet(WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext) {
        super(webApplicationContext);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doDispatch(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        if (!(request instanceof ContentCachingRequestWrapper)) {
            request = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        }
        if (!(response instanceof ContentCachingResponseWrapper)) {
            response = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
        }
        HandlerExecutionChain handler = getHandler(request);

        try {
            super.doDispatch(request, response);
        } finally {
            log(request, response, handler);
            updateResponse(response);
        }
    }

....

    private void updateResponse(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper =
                WebUtils.getNativeResponse(response, ContentCachingResponseWrapper.class);

        String encoding = responseWrapper.getCharacterEncoding();
        if (encoding.equals("windows-1251")) {
            String responseString = new String(responseWrapper.getContentAsByteArray(),"UTF-8");
            responseWrapper.resetBuffer();
            responseWrapper.getOutputStream().write(responseString.getBytes("windows-1251"));
            responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
        } else {
            responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
        }
    }

   ...
}
```